# strange "template-like" syntax (generics?)

Tags: java, generics

In the following line

```
Graph<Number,Number> ig = Graphs.<Number,Number>synchronizedDirectedGraph(
                              new DirectedSparseMultigraph<Number,Number>());
```

could you please explain what `Graphs.<Number,Number>synchronizedDirectedGraph` means ? It looks like a call to a method Graphs.synchronizedDirectedGraph, but the template-like thingie after the dot puzzles me (at least due to my C++ background).

Comment: Graph<Number,Number> ig -> Variable ig de type Graph avec les .......paramètres generic <Number,Number>.....

..Graphs. -> Appel d'une méthode statique de Graphs
......<Number,Number> -> paramètres generic de la méthode.....
synchronizedDirectedGraph -> nom de la méthode......
new DirectedSparseMultigraph<Number,Number>() -> Nouvelle instance........ deDirectedSparceMultigraph avec comme paramètres generic <Number,Number>

Comment: answer source: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d704051/java/general-java/probleme-ligne-code/

Comment: In C++ you would put the template arguments after the function name. Java distinguishes the syntax of generic types and generic methods (it also uses different name-spaces for types/fields and methods). Note, you do need the type in front for syntactical reasons (unless the generic arguments can be implied when you can miss the lot off).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Java is not very intelligent in the places it supports type inference.

For a method:

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class Y{
  static <T> List<T> x(T t)
}
```

It infers the type `List<B>` from the parameter type B

```
List<B> bs = Y.x(new B());
```

But if you need `List<A>` you have to cast B or add the compiler hint:

```
List<A> as1 = Y.<A> x(new B());
List<A> as2 = Y.x((A) new B());
```

Part of the problem is that java generics are invariant so `List<B>` is not a subtype of `List<A>`.

Answer (score 6):

It is specifying the types for the static method.  See [Generic Types, Part 2](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/index1.html) (particularly the "Generic mehods" section) for more information.